# Using XPath in sqlserver how do i return all the mixed content of a tag

Tags: html, sql-server, xpath

so for example

when selecting this node

```
<p>
   This is an open access article under the terms of the 
   <url href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution‐NonCommercial‐NoDerivs</url>
   License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non‐commercial and no modifications or adaptations are made.
</p>
```

there is simply text with a url tag that i would like to keep as such

currently i can select everything from it using the following sql

```
select
    isnull(pMetaUnitlegal.value('(*:p/node())[1]','varchar(255)') ,'')
    + isnull(pMetaUnitlegal.value('(*:p/node())[2]','varchar(255)') ,'')
    + isnull(pMetaUnitlegal.value('(*:p/node())[3]','varchar(255)') ,'') legal_statement
from XMLwithOpenXML
OUTER APPLY XMLData.nodes('/*:component/*:header/*:publicationMeta[@level = "unit"]/*:legalStatement') pmul(pMetaUnitlegal)
```

and i get

> This is an open access article under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non-commercial and no modifications or adaptations are made.

but what i really want is

```
<p>
   This is an open access article under the terms of the 
   <url href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution‐NonCommercial‐NoDerivs</url>
   License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non‐commercial and no modifications or adaptations are made.
</p>
```

with the html tag still embedded

i get less data when i use the `text()` evaluator. the url node gets dropped completely

> This is an open access article under the terms of the License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non-commercial and no modifications or adaptations are made.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

This data will be displayed from the db on a webpage so it would be great if i could save the html tags for use then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using XML method [`query()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) instead of `value()` to get the raw XML data, for example :

```
select
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pMetaUnitlegal.query('*:p')) legal_statement
from XMLwithOpenXML
OUTER APPLY 
    XMLData.nodes('/*:component/*:header/*:publicationMeta[@level = "unit"]/*:legalStatement') pmul(pMetaUnitlegal)
```

This is a working example for demo :

```
declare @xml XML = '<p>
   This is an open access article under the terms of the 
   <url href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution‐NonCommercial‐NoDerivs</url>
   License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non‐commercial and no modifications or adaptations are made.
</p>'

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @xml.query('p'))
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2086)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi har07.  That works beautifully thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3268030 you're welcome :) don't forget [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer then